# 'module' object has no attribute 'get'?

Tags: get, python-3.4

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def trade_spider(max_pages):
page = 1
while page <= max_pages:
    x = 16958 + int(page)
    url = 'http://mery.jp/' + str(x)
    source_code = request.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    print(soup)
    break

trade_spider(2)
```

when I try to run the code above in my Python3.4, I get an error that says the following:

```
File "web_crawler.py", line 15, in <module>
trade_spider(2)
File "web_crawler.py", line 9, in trade_spider
source_code = request.get(url)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get'
```

any ideas on how to fix this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You imported `request` from `urllib`, but `urllib.request` doesn't have a `get` method. I think you want to import the `requests` module and use `requests.get` in lieu of `request.get`. Either that or you want to replace `get` with `urlopen`. Considering that you reference the `.text` attribute in the next line, it probably is the former and not the latter.